# Visual Studio Extension for run/debug test handler?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-extensions

Is there a Visual Studio extension that adds a handler on a unit test to run/debug it.

If you worked with Resharper the handler looks like this.

[image: Resharper run/debug test handler]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/), which "makes it easy to run unit tests with a single click, anywhere in your Visual Studio solutions"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was after a free extension that has only one feature which is Unit Test handler